# Joining on multiple tables causing incorrect results

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to extract some data grouped by the markets we operate in. The table structure looks like this:

```
bks:
opportunity_id 

bks_opps:
opportunity_id | trip_start | state

bts:
boat_id | package_id

pckgs:
package_id | boat_id

addresses:
addressable_id | district_id

districts:
district_id
```

What I wanted to do is to count the number of won, lost and total and percentage won for each district.

```
SELECT          d.name AS "District",
                SUM(CASE WHEN bo.state IN ('won') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Won",
                SUM(CASE WHEN bo.state IN ('lost') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Lost",
                Count(bo.state) AS "Total",
                Round(100 * SUM(CASE WHEN bo.state IN ('won') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / Count(bo.state)) AS "% Won"              
FROM bks b
INNER JOIN bks_opps bo ON bo.id = b.opportunity_id
INNER JOIN pckgs p ON p.id = b.package_id
INNER JOIN bts bt ON bt.id = p.boat_id
INNER JOIN addresses a ON a.addressable_type = 'Boat' AND a.addressable_id = bt.id
INNER JOIN districts d ON d.id = a.district_id
WHERE bo.trip_start BETWEEN '2016-05-12' AND '2016-06-12'
GROUP BY d.name;
```

This returns incorrect data (The values are way higher than expected). However, when I get rid of all the joins and stop grouping by district - the numbers are correct (Counting the toal # of opportunities). Anybody that can spot what I am doing wrong? The most related question on here is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475182/postgres-multiple-joins-is-causing-my-query-to-return-incorrect-data) one.

Example data:

```
 District | won | lost | total 
----+---------+---------+------

  1 |       42 |    212 |   254
```

Expected data:

```
District | won | lost | total |
       ----+---------+---------+--
        1 |  22 |    155 |   177
```

Comment: start with `select distinct`

Comment: Still not working ....

Comment: You should provide example data to be able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: and expected for this example?..

Comment: I misunderstood. Hold on

Comment: I bet on districts vs addresses pair - remove only those two and see if numbers are fine. I think you either have several names for same district id or several addreses for it

Comment: Is it guaranteed to get exactly one address with `ON a.addressable_type = 'Boat' AND a.addressable_id = bt.id` per boat? (I.e. is `addressable_type` + `addressable_id` a unique key in `addresses`?)

Answer (score 2):

Formatted comment here:

I would venture a guess that one of your join conditions is at fault here, but with the provided structure it is impossible to say.

For instance, you have this join `INNER JOIN pckgs p ON p.id = b.package_id`, but `package_id` is not listed as a column in `bks`.

And these joins look especially suspect:

```
INNER JOIN pckgs p ON p.id = b.package_id
INNER JOIN bts bt ON bt.id = p.boat_id
```

If a boat can exist in multiple packages, it will be an issue.

To troubleshoot, start with the simplest query you can:

```
SELECT b.opportunity_id
FROM   bks b
```

Then leave the select alone, and proceed to add in each join:

```
SELECT b.opportunity_id
FROM   bks b
INNER JOIN pckgs p ON p.id = b.package_id
```

At some point you'll likely see a jump in the number of rows returned.  Whichever `JOIN` you added last is your issue.

Comment: package_id is in fact a column in bks.

Comment: @DavidBentzon-Ehlers Oh, I believe you.  I'm simply pointing out that there is at least one relation that isn't clearly defined for us.  Try the troubleshooting suggestion and report back if the number of rows returned ever changes.

Comment: No joins = 37894
1 join = 37833
2 joins = 37833
3 joins = 37833
4 joins = 37784
5 joins = 37769

Comment: @DavidBentzon-Ehlers Hmm I see.  Then your problem must be duplicate `ID`s in `bks`.  What row count does `SELECT DISTINCT opportunity_id FROM bks` return?

Comment: It returns 37913. I used `COUNT (DISTINCT opportunity_id)` for the record.

Comment: @DavidBentzon-Ehlers Wow, more interesting by the second.  What happens if you change `IN` to `=`: `CASE WHEN bo.state IN ('won')` to `CASE WHEN bo.state = 'won'`?

Comment: Nothing happens when I change that ... Same results.

Comment: @DavidBentzon-Ehlers I'm fresh out of ideas.  It's either a strange bug (unlikely), something about the data that I cannot or am not inferring, or something postgresql specific that I'm unaware of.  I'll leave the answer up for reference to what's been tried.